# How to solve newtemplate problem

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search

i need clarification on this, in my blogger previous template some junk text(not useful) things got indexed in google search, it was annoying.
so i reverted to Google classic templates.now those text got disappeared in my blog template.
its not reflected in Google search... what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the next update of the index?!! ;-)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.. how long it takes to update? on what basis it updates?.. what if i add custom domain how to update sitemap in that senario.. kindly help me

Comment: Can't say how long. Depends on the engines, but it can take weeks or months. Busy sites like SO or Twitter are very interesting for real-time indexing, sites with less users are not that important. If you have own domain f.e. with own Wordpress installation you can use a plug-in for a sitemap, meta "revisit" and google webmastertools. I don't know about using sitemap with blogger.